# Magento 2.2.9 question about foreach data into popup modal

Tags: javascript, frontend, phtml, array, modal-popup

I am trying to do a popup modal with this information I have in an array.
I have ID, NAME and DESCRIPTION

So in a function, I have done foreach to gather all the information and i am showing it on phtml by

```
       if ($ReleaseDate <= $currentTime){
            echo "<div>" ."ID => ". implode(" ", $product_id) . " NAME=> "  .$productData->getName() . " DESCRIPTION=>" .$productData->getDescription();"</div>";
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Currently, I get this following details :
ID => 1 
NAME=> test
DESCRIPTION =>testing product

I want to do a popup modal not sure if this is possible. 
First only show the ID and click ID to see NAME and DESCRIPTION